# Implementing a TreeSet in IntelliJ issue with overriding default methods

Tags: java, intellij-idea, data-structures

i'm currently practicing implementing my own abstract data structures for uni, however I'm having a issue with intelliJ.

I'm currently implementing a Binary Search Tree, apparently when I try and implement this (according to the lecture I'm watching) it should prompt for the methods void add, void remove, boolean contains and int size.

However when autofilling the methods that need to be implemented I get:
boolean add, boolean remove, boolean containsAll, boolean addAll, boolean retainAll, boolean removeAll and void clear.

It gets grumpy when I try and change the return type it gives a clash error attempting to use an incompatible return type.

I'm speculating it could be changed in Java 8 in comparison with the one used in my lectures.

The autogenerated skeletal class is:

```
public class BSTSet<T> implements Set<T>{
@Override
public void add(T element){

}

@Override
public void remove(T element){

}

@Override
public boolean contains(T element){
    return false
}

@Override
public int size(T element){
    return 0;
}
```

The code I get is:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
public class BSTSet<T> implements Set<T> {


@Override
public int size() {
    return elements;
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean contains(T element) {

    return false;
}

@Override
public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Object[] toArray() {
    return new Object[0];
}

@Override
public <T1> T1[] toArray(T1[] a) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean add(T element) {
    return falsee;
}

@Override
public boolean remove(Object o) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> c) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void clear() {
}
```

}

Comment: You really should post your code

Comment: "apparently when I try and implement this it should prompt..." According to who? `containsAll` and friends have always been a part of `Collection` interface. Is it possible you should be extending some partial implementation (e.g. `AbstractCollection`) rather than implementing `Set` directly?

Comment: I updated the question with the differing skeletal classes.

Comment: java.util.Set.add and remove have returned booleans forever.  Maybe you are importing the wrong Set interface?

Answer (score 0):

I think the comment is correct. If you're implementing java.util.Collection directly, you shouldn't be surprised to have to implement these methods yourself. The JavaDoc for java.util.AbstractCollection states pretty clearly:

> This class provides a skeletal implementation of the Collection interface, to minimize the effort required to implement this interface.

So that's probably what you want to extend in order to reduce the amount of boilerplate.

Comment: I've updated the question with the proper code of the skeletal class generated by the lecturers intellij vs my own. Thanks, I'll play around with it all and see if I can figure it out.